# Loop to Radically Change a 3x3 Grid of Array Elements

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a loop where I can do the following:-

```
x x x y y y y y
x x x y y y y y
x x x y y y y y
y y y y y y y y 
y y y y y y y y
```

(The above is an 8x5 grid, by the way.)

1. Grab all of the values marked as x
2. Sum all the 9 x values
3. Replace the x values with the value for the sum I just found
4. Then multiply all the x values by 1/9
5. Then move onto the next block of x values, like this:-

```
y y y x x x y y
y y y x x x y y
y y y x x x y y
y y y y y y y y 
y y y y y y y y
```

I've tried doing this:-

```
for(int j=0;j<image.rows;j++)
{
    for (int i=0;i<image.cols;i++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y < 9; y++) {
            sum = image.at<uchar>(j,i) + sum;
            change = sum/9;
        }
        image.at<uchar>(j,i) = change;
    }
}
```

But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the image pixel by pixel, but in order to do what you want, you'll need to iterate by group of 3x3 pixels:

```
for(int j = 0; j < image.rows; j += 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < image.cols; i += 3)
    { 
        uchar sum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                sum += image.at<uchar>(j + x,i + y);
            }
        }
        sum  /= 9;

        for(int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                image.at<uchar>(j + x,i + y) = sum ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to handle the case where the image dimensions are not multiple of 3.

Comment: Thanks so much, how would I handle such a case, for future reference?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get a localised average?

Comment: yes, then apply that average to the block in order to create a slightly blurred effect

Comment: Can I create a mask (that is a multiple of 3) over the image and only work on that mask? Mind you, the array is the mask...

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin It really depends on what you want to do. Traditionally in image processing we use different methods to handle boundaries, such as replication, reflection, wrapping. Take a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html) (second paragraph) for an example of methods to handle boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

@zakinster already gave you a good solution, but I would recommend you to use to use functions of OpenCV in order to perform operations like calculation of average or setting values, instead of using loops. This will create much shorter and more readable solution. Also you have to make sure that the algorithm will work when the image is not multiple of 3. Usual C++ trick for this case is use of (x/3*3) instead of x.

The code should look like this:

```
for(int j=0; j<image.rows/3*3; j+=3)
    for(int i=0; i<image.cols/3*3; i+=3)
    {
        Mat tmp(image,Rect(i,j,3,3));
        tmp.setTo(mean(tmp));
    }
```

Even shorter but less readable version of same code:

```
for(int j=0; j<image.rows/3*3; j+=3)
    for(int i=0; i<image.cols/3*3; i+=3)
        image(Rect(i,j,3,3)).setTo(mean(image(Rect(i,j,3,3))));
```

Comment: thank you for this, this really does help, I wish I could pick two great answers! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
    change = sum*(1/9);
```

1/9 is an integer division, so this will come out as zero. Use `change = sum/9.0` instead.

Comment: thanks, I've changed that. The code still has no effect, however.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your inner loop over the variable y never alters the values i or j. So, the first time you enter this loop you just basically multiply the value at (0, 0) in the image by 9 and then divide by 9.

You're going to have to figure out a way to perform a transform on i and j based on y, by editing this line probably:

`sum = image.at<uchar>(j, i) + sum;`

Such that it address the cells marked with x.

Then you will need to modify the way you update i and j in the outer loops. It looks like you're need to increment j by 3 in order to skip the block you just processed.

This will involve some thought and you'll need to think about how you handle the cases where the grid dimensions are not multiples of three, but I'd start with getting the inner loop working first.